# How does SQL Server handle logins when the user is a part of multiple groups with various privileges?

Tags: sql-server, security

I'm trying to wrap my head around how SQL Server decides to grant certain rights based on a users login privileges.  If a user is part of a group "READ ONLY" which has access to DB1, but they are also a part of a group "SysAdmin" which has full db owner rights to the same DB1, which rights are they given when they log in?  On a similar note. What if they are part of a group but also have a standalone account with other middle of the road privileges?

Comment: Simple way I think about it: `(sysadmin or readonly) = sysadmin` - basically, if they get rights one way then they have those rights even if they don't get them another way. The exception is `DENY` which overrides (except in the case of `sysadmin` IIRC). This is easy to set up and test (I'm just too lazy atm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For normal roles, permissions for all role memberships are cumulative and DENY takes precedence over GRANT.  However, sysadmin is a special case.  SQL Server permissions are not checked for sysadmin role members so members of that role have full permissions to all databases on the instance.